# How to read values from local file into Docker-compose environment variables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, docker-compose

I'm trying to inject my AWS Credentials from my local `~/.aws/credentials` file into a Docker container by setting environment variables in my `docker-compose.yml` file.

But I don't know how to read the credentials from the local file into the the docker-compose file. How can I do it??

Here is what my AWS credentials file looks like:

```
$ cat ~/.aws/credentials
[default]
aws_access_key_id = AK_FAKE_KEY_88RD3PNY
aws_secret_access_key = BividQsWW_FAKE_KEY_MuB5VAAsQNJtSxQQyDY2C
```

Here is what my the relevant part of my Docker compose file looks like:

```
  my_service:
    build: .
    image: my_image
    environment:
         - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<What should I put here?>
         - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<What should I put here?>
```

Comment: why not use IAM roles?

Comment: Even if I use IAM roles, I will have to copy the local ~/.aws/cli/cache/*.json file over into the new image in the Dockerfile, right? How is that easier than what I'm trying to do?

Comment: As I understood it and have used (admittedly limited times) i just made an IAM role, set up the instance with the role and that was it. I guess that assumes you are running on EC2. The config files take preference so I didnt even have any on my EC2 as they were interfering.

Comment: There are no EC2 instances. I'm running local docker containers on my laptop. One of the thing the docker containers need to do is to upload files to an S3 bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it need to be from your credentials file?

You could create `~/aws_env_creds` containing

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AK_FAKE_KEY_88RD3PNY
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=BividQsWW_FAKE_KEY_MuB5VAAsQNJtSxQQyDY2C
```

And then

```
my_service:
  build: .
  image: my_image
  env_file:
    - ~/aws_env_creds
```

Comment: Surely those env vars could get logged? Given that they are secrets, maybe not a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, generally speaking, it's not a good idea to hard-code home directory in `docker-compose.yml`, it's not going to be portable for others. I'll not object to having ~/.aws/credentials though since it's a convention that everyone will follow

```
my_service:
    build: .
    image: my_image
    environment:
         - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
         - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    volumes:
         - ~/.aws:/root/.aws:ro
```

This `docker-compose.yml` will be flexible enough that it depends on the setting of the machine, either the credential file or the environment variables will be used.

Comment: This worked for me, but can you explain why you still include the environment section? That doesn't seem to make a difference?

Comment: @GlennS errrr... honest I can't remember, it has been a couple of months. if it works for you after remove the `environment` section, then why not.